# Suddenly I can't connect to SQL Azure Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-sql-database, sequelize.js

I have been successfully using Sequelize to connect to the SQL Server Database for my website hosted on Azure for a few months now. Everything was fine until today. Today when I entered: `node server.js` I get this error:

> ```
> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Login failed for user 'EventAdmin'.
>     at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:103:16)
>     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>     at Connection.emit (events.js:169:7)
>     at Connection.processLogin7Response (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:712:16)
>     at Connection.message (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1120:21)
>     at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:559:45)
>     at MessageIO.<anonymous> (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:479:23)
>     at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>     at MessageIO.emit (events.js:166:7)
>     at ReadablePacketStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:103:15)
>     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>     at ReadablePacketStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
>     at readableAddChunk (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:201:16)
>     at ReadablePacketStream.Readable.push (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:165:10)
>     at ReadablePacketStream.Transform.push (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:133:32)
>     at ReadablePacketStream._transform (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:68:16)
>     at ReadablePacketStream.Transform._read (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:10)
>     at ReadablePacketStream.Transform._write (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:160:12)
>     at doWrite (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:335:12)
>     at writeOrBuffer (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:321:5)
>     at ReadablePacketStream.Writable.write (C:\Users\v-mibowe\Documents\repositories\event-site\node_modules\tedious\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:248:11)
>     at CleartextStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:528:20)
> ```

I'm sure all of the login info is correct, because it was working yesterday, and the website is still live online using the same login info. I connect to the database with this:

```
var sql = new Sql(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASS, {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  dialect: 'mssql',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
  dialectOptions: {
    encrypt: true
  }
});
```

I have tried doing `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm cache clear` and `npm install`, but it didn't make any difference. I have also tried using a different computer, but it has the same problem. I also went on Azure and reset the password to make sure that it was correct, but it had no effect.

Please let me know if more information will help. You can see the full project on [my GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mrbgit/event-site). Thanks if advance for all you help!

Okay, so it randomly started working again, but then after I restarted the server (without changing anything) the login started to fail again. The thing is, I didn't change anything, so I have no idea what to do to fix it...

Even more annoying, it started working again the next day, but now it is failing again. Please let me know if you need more information, I really appreciate you help!

Comment: Yay, random hacker changed your password!  (just kidding)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I reset the password on Azure, so I'm sure that this the password is correct.

Comment: Maybe the Sql Server firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: @SamAxe That's a good suggestion, but I have been using this IP (I'm at work) for months now. I checked anyway just to make sure and there is an exception for my IP address.

Comment: Have to love these "something changed now what was it" proverbial pin in a haystack..

Comment: Makes you wonder what updates got applied etc.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I would give you more info if I had it, but I am really at a loss for what could be wrong. If you have any questions, let me know and I will do my best to answer them.

Comment: This is extremely interesting. Did you try connecting to your Azure SQL DB from a tool like SSMS? May be also try connecting to your Azure SQL DB using Tedious. Let me know if you have any luck with that.

Comment: @meet-bhagdev I Thanks for your advice. I tried to connect with Tedious and that connected successfully, but when I tried to connect with SSMS it gave me the error that my IP address was being blocked by the firewall. I looked at the Azure firewall settings and the IP address I had set as an exception was different from what was showing in the SSMS error. I added another exception to the Azure firewall and Sequelize connects again. I guess they changed our IP address, which still leaves me with the question: Why was Tedious able to connect, but not Sequelize? Thanks again!

Comment: Very interesting. Do you have a log with traces? We need to look at the failures to understand why does Sequelize not connect.